# How to restrict download file for authentication in drupal

Tags: hooks, files

I have create one file field in my node create form , file is accepting (txt,pdf,xlx,docx) files only.
 but in node view page, i want to authenticate our file before download.

I have create one term and condition checkbox, if user check this term and condition checkbox , then he should be able to download the file..

This functionality i need to do, please suggest me any module is available for this..

or if this functionality is possible through conditional fields , so please suggest me, how can i do

Comment: Using Ajax you can do that, just make a ajax call once the authenticated user check the checkbox. Check the conditions and provide the download button.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Field Permission Module](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions)

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

[Demo Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmqlBBSoRWU)

Comment: Also, if file is stored in public filesystem, it will be publicly available even if field that refers it is not. So in addition to Field Permission module, storage should be set to private file system. Documentation [here](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file).

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for the pointer :) 
I think this will solve the problem, "making all the files private in the field settings and assigning Roles to download files using this module."

https://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission

Comment: If it works, sure, but it's "minimally maintained, maintenance fixes only" and has some old open bugs. Personally I think that Field Permissions to hide links to files, and private filesystem to protect linked files themselves, is the most stable combination.

Comment: no i am not talking about, file is private or public,  my question is , i want to create this:- before download file, check one checkbox for user, i need to create this.... without click checkbox.. he should not be download file

Comment: @SachinTonte well in that case Did you try this module, it seems work as you said. 

https://drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state

Comment: ok i will try, i have not used FCS  ... but i am using in my project conditional field

Comment: i want to provide condition not in form page, i want to provide condition in node display page.. but conditional field is work for only  node creation page

Comment: @SachinTonte then you need a private filesystem and appropriate form handler. Sadly, the one shrish mentioned above seems to only work at edit, not display. Closest I was able to find is the Legal module, I posted [a feature request](https://drupal.org/node/2266035) for Sachin's use case. Follow it if you want to show maintainers your support with this issue :)